# Webpage not displaying when folder of the same name exists

Tags: php, .htaccess, wamp

I am building a website using WampServer to develop locally, and my current structure is as follows:

```
/css/
/js/
/pictures/
index.php
blog.php
games.php
.htaccess
```

Everything was working fine, until I created a folder titled "/blog". This immediately broke my blog.php page. Now I've removed the folder, restarted WampServer and restarted my whole computer, but the error still persists. For some reason when I go to mysite/blog, it redirects to mysite/blog/ and returns an internal server error. The games page has no such problem. If I rename blog.php to myblog.php, the problem is resolved, so it is only related to the name of the file.

So is deleting the file not enough? Do I need to refresh WampServer somehow?

If it is important, this is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to accomplish with your current htaccess rules?

Comment: To be honest, I'm new to this and grabbed it from a tutorial. What I want it to do is display my pages without the extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the htaccess file and the naming convention you've chosen.

this line in particular

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Says if the file is not a directory use the rewrite. in the case of /blog the condition is not met and htaccess does not pull blog.php since /blog IS in fact a directory. Removing the folder should have been enough to fix it, but to be honest this is asking for trouble. Why not just go to blog.php?

Comment: I don't like the look of the .php extension in the url, is there a safer way to remove it? I don't really understand htaccess files.

Comment: Not the way you're doing it. The answer is avoid having folders with the same name as files or deal with the extension.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks. Now I just have to sort out why deleting the folder didn't help.

Comment: yeah that part doesn't make sense.Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

mysite/blog is going to look in the blog folder if one exists for an index.php file.

you can still have both file and folder with the same name (given your current .htaccess), you just need to access blog.php by going to mysite/blog.php

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try. You should turn of multiviews so that it doesn't try a pattern match and do weird things. Make sure to clear your browser cache after updating .htaccess.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```